# How to change a global int in SpriteKit with Swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

So im coding a similar game to 4 images 1 word. I want that when i'm for example at level 5 and I close the Game and delete it out of my history, then go back to the game again and press Play I can resume at level 5. I tried that with a global Variable(LevelNumber) wich is a int and has the value of 1 that means it is above the classLevel1: Skscene{ :

```
var levelNumber = 1
class Level1: SKScene {
```

In the Win function of level 1 i put the value of levelNumber to 2 (because you finished Level 1) and save that:

```
func Win() {
    levelNumber == 2
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(levelNumber, forKey: "levelNumber")
}
```

*edit In the MainMenu Scene I said:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if levelNumber == 1 {
    let Level = Level1(size: self.size)
    Level.scaleMode = scaleMode
    let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)
    self.view?.presentScene(Level, transition: transition)
    }

    else if levelNumber == 2{
        let Level = Level2(size: self.size)
        Level.scaleMode = scaleMode
        let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)
        self.view?.presentScene(Level, transition: transition)
    }

    else if levelNumber == 3 {
        let Level = Level3(size: self.size)
        Level.scaleMode = scaleMode
        let transition = SKTransition.fadeWithDuration(0.5)
        self.view?.presentScene(Level, transition: transition)
    }
```

And so on for all the levels.

Heres the code in the AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var oldScore : Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("oldScore")
var oldlevelNumber : Int = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("oldlevelNumber")

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    Score += oldScore
    levelNumber += oldlevelNumber
    return true
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(Score, forKey: "oldScore")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(levelNumber, forKey: "oldlevelNumber")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
}
```

But for some reason when I press Play, go to Level 1(not calling the win function), then restart the game and press Play I go to Level 2 without even Winning Level 1, why?

Comment: `LevelNumber` is not the same as `levelNumber`. Also, variables should always begin with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Sorry, i wrote that wrong, in my code its the same as the others so its a lowercase L.

Comment: Where is `Score` created?

Comment: look at my edit maybe you can see a mistake i made in the MainMenu Scene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Win function, set your variable like this:

```
levelNumber = 2
```

Instead of

```
levelNumber == 2
```

Comment: Your current code seems fine... Could you show some more?

Comment: Your code for retrieving your NSUserDefault information

Comment: thats the AppDelegate Code where i save my levelNumber:

Comment: its too long, one moment

Comment: Try declaring your oldScore and oldlevelNumber in the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.

Comment: Still doesn't work, its probably in the MainMenu Scene because the saving of the Score works completely fine.

Comment: Could you show me the code, and I can help you out with that scene

Comment: After declaring your oldScore and oldLevelNumber variables in the application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, print it. Let me know what you get

Comment: the value of the levelNumber is 1 but for some reason when i press Play nothing happens although it should go to level 1.

Comment: Print levelNumber before the if statements and then inside if levelNumber == 1 { put another print to see if that section is running

Comment: the one before the if levelNumber == 1{ has the value of 1, the one inside the if levelNumber == 1{ is also 1. But when i now restart the game and press Play it goes to Level 2 but the print which is inside the else if levelNumber == 2{ doesn't called which is very weird because it has to be called, otherwise it wouldn't go to Level 2.

Comment: Try putting a return after the end of each if statement

Comment: I did that and when i restart the game  and tap Play, nothing happens. Also after the return, it says "Code after return will never be executed". Do you know what else i could do? i really want to fix that because that is the last thing left in my game except for ad's maybe :D

Comment: You are putting the return in the wrong place. It should go in each of statement right after the self.view?.presentScene

Comment: Otherwise, you can send me your project via Github or email, and I can clean it up and help you out.

Comment: How can i send you a private message or should i just post the link here?

Comment: Just post a link to Github. I will find it

Comment: is this ok? I'm not used to Github, first time I'm using it.

Comment: Yes it's fine. I will look at it

Comment: @LukasDomeisen I just pulled your project. You only uploaded your project to Github. You need to upload the other files as well. On the main file (the one in which when you tap to open, you see the project and the supporting files) right click and select compress. Then upload it

Comment: Got it! I will fix it up and send it to you

Comment: I just noted a bug in your code. Go to Level1.swift - in the win function, you are setting levelNumber to NSUserDefaults, however, you have not changed it. Add "levelNumber = 2" to right before that line. This may be what is going wrong. I suggest that after you fix this, delete the app from your simulator to reset NSUserDefaults. Then run it again

Comment: I found the real bug!!!!! Your keys were wrong. You were saving the Score as totalScore and levelNumber as levelNumber. However, when you were retrieving it, you looked for oldScore and oldLevelNumber. You do not need the code in the appWillTerminate. Here is the link to your fixed project: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=764D5C6241541226!62880&authkey=!ALERHZhmgWmnoxk&ithint=file%2czip

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you'd want to assign `score` and `levelNumber` rather than add to them.

What you have:

```
score += oldScore
levelNumber += oldlevelNumber
```

What you probably want:

```
score = oldScore
levelNumber = oldlevelNumber
```

Comment: @LukasDomeisen I'd suggest relearning some basics of Swift before continuing any further with your application. You're going to run into alot of issues if you don't know the difference between `+=` and `=`, or `=` and `==`.

Comment: I'm almost finished with the game, thats the only thing left i can't just give up now. And if you can't find a solution i will find someone else who maybe will.

Comment: @LukasDomeisen this is the correct answer. In the situation you described, you skipped level 1 and went to level 2. This is because you are adding the oldScore to the new score. If you just set it, it would be 1. If you were to run the project again, you would be at level 3. This answe should work for you